# Listen again to open socket after server restart

Tags: java, sockets

Is it possible that I will close(forcibly) server and then start it so the other side will not notice it? Some SO_ADDRREUSE or Linger time magic possible??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that is possible. When you stop your server socket, you lose any TCP connection information, so any traffic will have to establish a new connection after the server restarts.

Comment: Could a proxy server not help with this situation? Let the client not directly talk to the server and have it go through proxy. Proxy holds the connection and connects to the real server on client's behalf. Could silently retry connection and act as if nothing happened.

Comment: Not a bad idea. You should add it as an answer

Comment: So to summarize technically it is impossible for the other side to continue without knowing. It is more about accidental situation than wanted one. Normally the client handles it by reconnecting. I expect the problem will be with server not knowing the sequence TCP number for the client(as it was reset). So I guess the problem is with that numbers being out of sync.